# Webapp on Citrix and sessions issue

Tags: session, laravel, citrix

Does anyone know about sessions mix ups when webapp running through Citrix client.

We experience issues with users being mixed up when our laravel application is accessed through a Citrix client.

The sessions are stored as files currently.

Comment: How do you identify a session in your web app? If you're running in a Citrix environment you'll get multiple users running on the same client machine (i.e. the Citrix server). So for example if you used the client IP address as your session identifier then multiple users would have the same identity.

Comment: Got the same issue..Have you found a fix for this?